# How to properly implement Find in Files in Custom Project?

Tags: vsix

I tried implement interface IVsProjectTextImageProvider. Method OpenItemTextImage is called for each file in project (files are packed inside project files - something like zip) but in there is still no result in Find Results window.

What i am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams that item must be registered in Running Document Table.